# Is it ever illegal to spread true facts with malicious intent?

Tags: defamation, libel, securities, hate-crime

Crimes such as defamation usually require that the statement being said is false - truth is an absolute defense.

Are there any situations or jurisdictions where truth is **not** a defense against defamation, incitement to hatred, or similar crimes or torts?

For example:

- Malicious gossip: widely spreading word that someone cheated on their wife. Their employer hears about it and fires them. Otherwise their employer had no reason to know this.
- Facts out of context: "Mr XYZ won't deny being a pedophile" but only because he hangs up every time the reporter asks.
- Plain old defamation, in some jurisdictions.
- Contextual implication: "Black people commit more than 50% of violent crimes" [because they are inherently violent beings and something should be done to control them]
- Stock price manipulation: "XYZ Corp is doing terribly" [so is every company in that sector but I want the price of XYZ Corp in particular to go down]

Comment: Is this under contemporary laws or historical ones?  I know that some historical laws punished maliciously spread truths.

Comment: @Mary I think the question would be off-topic if it asked for historical laws as well

Comment: @user253751 Questions on legal history are on topic, as well.

Comment: @bdb484 then I suppose those answers would be interesting and could be posted, even though they are not direct answers, similar to the rule about other jurisdictions.

Comment: In some countries its illegal to post negative reviews, even if "true."  Also, it would be breach of contract to speak the truth, if you signed a NDA or something similar.  Giving away governmental classified information, as well.

Comment: also, "Facts" by definition, are true.  You cant have a false fact.

Comment: You cannot sue for defamation or libel, only for getting it removed, so this is not an answer for your question, but maybe interesting anyway: In Germany, written references from a job *must* be in a form "not obstructing the further development of the person". So "Was constantly drunk on the job until I fired them" would be a sentence you could take to court and probably win to get it removed, even if it is 100% true and independent witnesses can confirm.

Comment: Also many laws in various jursitictions limit what you can post publicly about other people. My employer or doctor would not be allowed to post my sick note publicly. Even if it is my sick note and what is on it is the truth. Does that count for your question?

Comment: Also... are we talking about a private person spreading those facts to their 5 friends, or a publication publishing it (newspaper, big streamer etc).

Comment: @Keltari In the law, "facts" are not necessarily true. Especially in the context of defamation and related areas of law, we talk about "facts" as being true or false, as distinct from opinions, which are not falsifiable.

Comment: Fairly certain forms of insider trading, like providing non-publicly disclosed information to a person, falls under this.

Comment: @nvoigt "*In Germany, written references from a job must be in a form "not obstructing the further development of the person".*" Can you provide sources?

Comment: @IñakiViggers You can read more about it here: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/57219/i-was-let-go-because-i-internally-fought-against-unlawful-overtime-how-do-i-exp/57222#57222. If you want the direct link to the court decision, use your favorite tool to discover German court decisions and look for "BGH, 26.11.1963 - VI ZR 221/62" In case you are not familiar, BGH is the highest German court, so this is an accepted ruling, not just some random country court deciding a single case.

Comment: If the answer is yes then it certainly isn't enforced.  If it were, many mainstream media outlets and most politicians would implode.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ygtFc3eR6So

Comment: i wonder about statements that are factually true, but misleading. Like me saying "X was charged with murder" when it turned out in court that someone else committed the crime, and X would have been found "innocent beyond reasonable doubt" if such a judgement existed. Assuming I fully well know that X was charged, but innocent.

Answer (score 5):

[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)

**Yes**

As well as the general offence of [comtempt of court](https://www.gov.uk/contempt-of-court) by publishing facts in breach of a court order, there are also two statutory provisions making it an offence if those facts reveal a person's identity (maliciously or not):

- [section 1](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1992/34/section/1?timeline=false), Sexual Offences (Amendment) Act 1992:

> (1) Where an allegation has been made that an offence to which this Act applies has been committed against a person, no matter relating to that person shall during that person’s lifetime be included in any publication if it is likely to lead members of the public to identify that person as the person against whom the offence is alleged to have been committed.
>
> (2) Where a person is accused of an offence to which this Act applies, no matter likely to lead members of the public to identify a person as the person against whom the offence is alleged to have been committed (“the complainant”) shall during the complainant’s lifetime be included in any publication.
>
> [...]

The relevant offences are listed in [section 2](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1992/34/section/2?timeline=false) (being rape and a number of other serious sexual offences).

- [section 49](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/Geo5/23-24/12/section/49?timeline=false), Children and Young Persons Act 1933:

> (1) No matter relating to any child or young person concerned in proceedings to which this section applies shall while he is under the age of 18 be included in any publication if it is likely to lead members of the public to identify him as someone concerned in the proceedings.
>
> (2) The proceedings to which this section applies are—
>
> - (a) proceedings in a youth court;
> - (b) proceedings on appeal from a youth court (including proceedings by way of case stated);
> - (c) proceedings in a magistrates' court under Schedule 7 to the Sentencing Code (proceedings for breach, revocation or amendment of youth rehabilitation orders);
> - (d) proceedings on appeal from a magistrates' court arising out of any proceedings mentioned in paragraph (c) (including proceedings by way of case stated).
>
> [...]

Comment: Allegations are by definition not "true facts" per the question.

Comment: @MichaelHall Quite right but the **identities** of those who make, or are on the receiving end, of the allegations are "true facts".

Comment: There’s also the Official Secrets Act. If you maliciously publish the designs of the UK’s nuclear warheads with the intention that other countries will gain access to them, that’s certainly a serious crime.

Comment: @MikeScott That's a pretty good answer, you should post it

Answer (score 5):

[united-states](/questions/tagged/united-states) except as otherwise stated.

> Is it ever illegal to spread true facts with malicious intent?

This is not a comprehensive answer, but illustrates some examples and counterexamples.

**Confidentiality Obligations**

The most common circumstance where it is illegal to spread true facts with malicious intent is when the person doing so has a legal duty, that obligates that person to keep certain information secret and maliciously breaches that duty in a way that harms someone whose information was protected.

This could arise, for example:

- out of a contract (such as a non-disclosure agreement or confidentiality term in a settlement agreement or a confidentiality provision related to a bid),
- a relationship (such as attorney-client, or psychotherapist-patient or an intimate sexual relationship in which photos or videos are taken without consent), or
- some other circumstance (such as cheating on an official government exam by spreading the answers, holding a position of trust in a publicly held company, grand jury service, providing health insurance to an insured, working for the IRS or a bank or an adoption agency or a spy or a soldier).

It could also happen in the absence of any specialized duty, for example, when national security is impaired as a result, or when it has the practical effect of foreseeably aiding and abetting someone imminently about to commit a crime against someone (e.g. telling an assassin or kidnapper that his target is hiding in the closet).

**Extortion**

Threatening to maliciously disclose truthful information, without actually disclosing the information, to make someone do something that otherwise wouldn't do, is in some circumstances illegal extortion. This is obvious not, however, actual dissemination of true facts with malicious intent. The perpetrators goal is to get compliance not to carry out the threat.

**Intentional Infliction Of Emotional Distress (a.k.a. Outrageous Conduct)**

The tort of intentional infliction of emotional distress could qualify, but then the gravamen of the tort is not spreading true information, but the manner in which an interaction is framed to humiliate someone.

This tort (and crimes in a handful of jurisdictions) could conceivably include "pushing someone's buttons" by means including dissemination of truthful facts with malicious intent with the purpose of trying to make them commit suicide. In these cases the goal to be accomplished and the intended effect on the vulnerable victim, rather than the actual content of the communication in the abstract is what matters.

**Verbal Acts**

Some statements that are true in a tautological sense (i.e. by definition) but not because they convey information about pre-existing facts, can give rise to liability.

For example, if I say "Your fired" which becomes true when I say it, and I was not allowed to terminate someone's employment that could give rise to liability.

Or, if I have a contract to deliver widgets and I say, "I'm not going to deliver the widgets" that could give rise to liability as a repudiation of a contract that breaches a contract.

Or, if I have a contract that obligates me to sell something to one person, and I sell it to someone else saying "I hereby sell this to you.", that is a verbal act which could also create liability for breaching the original contract.

**Examples From The Question**

The examples given in the question mostly don't give rise to liability. For example, if none of the duties of confidentiality illustrated above apply:

> Malicious gossip: widely spreading word that someone cheated on their
> wife. Their employer hears about it and fires them. Otherwise their
> employer had no reason to know this.

No, if true.

> Facts out of context: "Mr XYZ won't deny being a pedophile" but only
> because he hangs up every time the reporter asks.

A few states recognize the tort of "[false light](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/false_light)", although this would be a minority rule. It flows from linguistic context that falsely implies an untrue fact without actually saying so.

> Plain old defamation, in some jurisdictions.

Germany recognizes insults and disrespect as offenses and classifies them as defamation even though U.S. law would not classify this kind of conduct as defamation. The mere facts alone, moreover, as opposed to the context and manner as well as what is said, impact whether this is wrongful conduct in Germany.

In the U.S. the closest one gets are crimes and torts like disturbing the peace, interfering with a law enforcement officer, harassment, and inciting a riot. Mostly, these offenses are not focused on any particular banned truthful content. They are focused on the intended effect of the communication and the manner and context of the communication.

Historically, statements dishonoring the dead, or pointing out the natural frailties of the disabled could be grounds for civil or criminal defamation in the U.S. although these grounds have virtually vanished and are currently legally in doubt.

Egging someone on to engage in illegal or violent conduct (i.e. taunting them) with truthful statements made with malicious intent could have impacts on the right to self-defense and could mitigate the offense of someone who rises to the taunts (but is rarely a complete excuse).

> Contextual implication: "Black people commit more than 50% of violent
> crimes" [because they are inherently violent beings and something
> should be done to control them]

Not under U.S. law.

> Stock price manipulation: "XYZ Corp is doing terribly" [so is every
> company in that sector but I want the price of XYZ Corp in particular
> to go down]

Very unlikely to give rise to liability. There is securities fraud in the form of market manipulation, but generally this doesn't include spreading truthful information.

Usually market manipulation flows from conduct (as opposed to statements of fact or concealment of information) related to securities that is part of a scheme to defraud.

> Hate crimes

Under U.S. law "hate crimes" are generally always sentence enhancers for other acts that already constitute crimes. Disseminating truthful information with a malicious purpose is essentially never a hate crime.

> incitement to hatred

This concept is not recognized in U.S. law. U.S. law does impose liability for conduct that is discriminatory based upon improper considerations, but this is more along the lines of liability for verbal acts than malicious distribution of true information.

U.S. law does recognize crimes such as inciting a riot and solicitation of a crime, both of which contemplate urging other people to *imminently* commit a crime.

Comment: To give an example of False Light where true facts were used, in Braun v. Flynt (5th Cir. 1984), the court allowed a woman to sue a "gentleman's magazine" for publishing her photograph (which was not explicit) in the magazine because the overall implication was damaging, even though the photo was not itself obscene, nor was it misattributed to her.

Answer (score 3):

### Yes

The “truth” of a publication is determined not just by whether it is facially true but by the impression that the totality would create in a reasonable person. This is known as defamation by implication. Here’s some discussion of this from [Virginia](https://www.virginiadefamationlawyer.com/defamation-by-implication-is-an-intentional-tort/), [Iowa](https://www.rcfp.org/true-statements-can-be-defamatory-implication/), and the general [US](https://kellywarnerlaw.com/defamation-by-implication) on the basis that if its defamation in the USA, its defamation anywhere.

> Defamation by implication cases are nuanced. To win, you must have rock solid arguments and evidence to support your side.

For your examples:

- Malicious gossip - not defamatory. “Someone” cheated on their wife and that’s exactly what you are saying. Your motives for saying it are irrelevant.
- Out of context facts - may be defamatory. Your specific example would depend on the total context where the statement is made - in an article about allegations of child abuse, it’s probably defamatory without the specifics. It implies something more than “Mr XYZ gave no comment when asked”.
- Contextual implication - may be defamatory. Your particular example because “black people” is not a person who can be defamed. If the statement is made with some relationship to an individual so that the implication is that that person is more likely a criminal then it could be defamation.
- Talking down a company - may be defamatory. “XYZ corp is doing terribly” isn’t though because it’s a statement of opinion.

Comment: negligence is sufficient?  So if I tell a joke about someone, and I tell it poorly enough someone things I'm sincere I could be guilty of defamation?  What if a stranger overhears a joke between a friend and I who understand some injoke but without knowledge of that injoke it is reasonable for a third party to presume I'm serious am I now guilty of defamation of the person joked about?

Comment: You answer "yes" but then systematically dismantle each example the OP provided.  Seems the best answer is "maybe"...

Comment: @MichaelHall the answer to the headline question *is* yes, the OP’s examples just aren’t very good illustrations of the principle.

Comment: You say "Yes", but the answer is no, and that's essentially what your answer says. In all of your examples, the message the speaker intends to deliver, and does in fact deliver, is not true. When someone says or writes something, and they intend to deliver a particular message and do in fact deliver that message, that is what that message means in that context. And in the US, for defamation by implication, the implication must have been intended.

Answer (score 2):

[france](/questions/tagged/france)

A bit far from defamation etc. but given that stock manipulation is listed among the OP’s examples, I think "swindling" qualifies:

> L'escroquerie est le fait, soit par l'usage d'un faux nom ou d'une fausse qualité, **soit par l'abus d'une qualité vraie, soit par l'emploi de manoeuvres frauduleuses,** de tromper une personne physique ou morale et de la déterminer ainsi, à son préjudice ou au préjudice d'un tiers, à remettre des fonds, des valeurs ou un bien quelconque, à fournir un service ou à consentir un acte opérant obligation ou décharge.

> It is swindling to deceive a natural or moral person by using a false name or title, **or by abusing a true title, or by fraudulent maneuvers**; such that this person [gives money or does some stuff]

([Code Pénal, article 313-1](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/codes/article_lc/LEGIARTI000006418192); my emphasis. Under 313-3 an unsuccessful attempt is punished as well.)

"Fraudulent maneuvers" is a rather ill-defined thing. Cases about it regularly reach the Cour de Cassation ([here’s one two weeks ago (March 2023)](https://www.dalloz-actualite.fr/flash/escroquerie-necessite-de-manoeuvres-frauduleuses-determinantes-de-remise-et-anterieures-celle-)); most such appeals fail, but there is still enough uncertainty that many litigants will "roll the dice". Essentially it must be multiple actions or assertions designed to give a false belief to the recipient(s) (a one-time lie is not sufficient).

For instance, suppose a policeman intends to steal money from a bank and then run out of the country. He puts on his uniform, enters the bank, and tells the clerk: "I am from the police; someone is going to try to steal your money today, please give it to me." He did not lie (he is from the police, and someone - him - is trying to steal the money). Arguably he is not using "fraudulent maneuvers" either. He is still guilty of swindling (regardless of whether he succeeds), because his authority as a policeman is crucial for the scam to work.

Comment: I must say, this is a genius bank robbery plan.